# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'model' while model word is not written anywhere,

Tags: python, django, django-models

In djnago I have created Download model and it worked as expected but later when I tried to add new model 'Model' it just showing

> AttributeError: 'Music' object has no attribute 'model'.

models.py looks like this:

```py
from django.db import models

# Download/models.py.
class Download(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    discription = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imgages = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Music(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and here is an admin file

```py
# Download/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Download,Music
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Download,Music)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass two parameters to the `register` function, the first one is the model, and the second one is the `ModelAdmin` class for that model. Here you use it to register two models at once.

You can [register a model without a `ModelAdmin` [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) by only specifying the model, but you thus can not specify multiple ones. You thus register the models with:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Download,Music

admin.site.register(Download)
admin.site.register(Music)
```

Answer (score 0):

in Music you have self.name and I suppose you mean self.title